# NewContractNotFunded Error after submitting a smart contract on BereSheet

Tags: smart-contract, error

I'm trying to upload the flipper contract to Beresheet (Edgeware testnet) but after submitting, I got this contract.NewContractNotFunded error and the extrinsic failed.
I search the error on Google and found [this description](https://docs.rs/pallet-contracts/2.0.0/pallet_contracts/enum.Error.html):

> The newly created contract is below the subsistence threshold after executing its contructor. No contracts are allowed to exist below that threshold.

And this:

> **Subsistence Threshold**
> The runtime must make sure that any allowed dispatchable makes sure that the total_balance of the contract stays above Pallet::subsistence_threshold(). Otherwise users could clutter the storage with contracts.

What exactly the `total_balance` of a contract is? How can I resolve this problem?

Side question: Is there anyway to call a smart contract in the polkadot.js UI?

Answer (score 1):

with the Edgeware-specified `contracts` pallet,

https://github.com/webb-tools/substrate/blob/656e206faaf0353c7e7f14689779379018bbb02a/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L771-L780

```
    /// Subsistence threshold is the extension of the minimum balance (aka existential deposit)
    /// by the tombstone deposit, required for leaving a tombstone.
    ///
    /// Rent or any contract initiated balance transfer mechanism cannot make the balance lower
    /// than the subsistence threshold in order to guarantee that a tombstone is created.
    ///
    /// The only way to completely kill a contract without a tombstone is calling `seal_terminate`.
    pub fn subsistence_threshold() -> BalanceOf<T> {
        T::Currency::minimum_balance().saturating_add(T::TombstoneDeposit::get())
    }
```

so it's basically sum of two constants, `balances.existentialDeposit` and `contracts.TombstoneDeposit`.

you can get these constants by querying chain state.

[image]